# How to clear outputted values in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with a lot of different outputs (data preparation functions, clustering, modeling etc.), and when the user uploads a file some of them start calculating. Therefore there is a problem when he decides to upload a different file without refreshing the page: due to bad architecture a lot of outputs that depend on reactives crash the app. So here is a question: is there a way to clear `cache` (if you can call it so) in a shiny app?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer. Why do the outputs crash? What errors do they give? The best solution seems to improve your architecture...

Comment: The app is thousands lines of code, rewriting it is not an option, unfortunately. The question is not about crashes or errors, but about how do you prevent those output's to update when the dataset changes - in the best case to revert them to the state where they've been at the start of an user `session`.

Comment: I know about `shinyjs`'s `reset()` function. I wonder if there is something similar concerning `*output` and `render*` values